# C# MongoDB - How to select nested properties only

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is what my classes look like:

```cs
public class TestA : MongoDocument
{
    public string ProjectID { get; set; }
    public TestB Content { get; set; }

}

public class TestB
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<TestC> CustInfo { get; set; }
}

public class TestC
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public CustomerComment CustomerComment { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerComment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to return only the CustomerComment based on `TestA.ProjectID` && `TestC.Id`

```cs
var projection = Builders<TestA>.Projection
                   .Include(x => x.Content.CustInfo);

var options = new FindOptions<TestA>
{
    Projection = projection
};

var find = await Collection.FindAsync(p => p.ProjectID == "555" && 
                    p.Content.CustInfo.Any(l => l.Id == "123"), options).ConfigureAwait(false);
var result = await find.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This works but it will return everything. In this case, I would only want to return CustomerComments.

So for me to only retrieve the customerComments, I do another query based on the results from mongo. The code below gives me the correct data but I would rather do the filtering through the database.

```cs
var test = result.SelectMany(x => x.Content.CustInfo.Where(l => l.Id == "123").Select(y => y.CustomerComment)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Aggregation Query meets your requirements for querying the data in the database and returning desired output.

1. `$match` - Filtering data.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct array fields to multiple documents.
3. `$match` - Filtering data for `Content.CustInfo`.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the current document with the new document for output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "ProjectID": "555",
      "Content.CustInfo.Id": "123"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Content.CustInfo"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Content.CustInfo.Id": {
        $eq: "123"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$Content.CustInfo.CustomerComment"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zq4AMVgbTPT)

---

### Solution 1: With `AggregateFluent`

Pre-requisite: Create unwind classes.

```cs
public class UnwindTestA
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectID { get; set; }

    public UnwindTestB Content { get; set; }
}

public class UnwindTestB
{        
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public TestC CustInfo { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var result = await Collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(
        p => p.ProjectID == "555"
        && p.Content.CustInfo.Any(l => l.Id == "123")
    )
    .Unwind<TestA, UnwindTestA>(x => x.Content.CustInfo)
    .Match<UnwindTestA>(x => x.Content.CustInfo.Id == "123")
    .ReplaceWith<CustomerComment>("$Content.CustInfo.CustomerComment")
    .ToListAsync();
```

---

### Solution 2: With BsonDocument

Sometimes, writing a query with `AggregateFluent` is quite complex. You can use the MongoDB query which is converted to `BsonDocument`.

```cs
BsonDocument[] aggregate = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$match",
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "ProjectID", "555" },
                { "Content.CustInfo.Id", "123" }
            }),
    new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$Content.CustInfo"),
    new BsonDocument("$match",
        new BsonDocument("Content.CustInfo.Id",
            new BsonDocument("$eq", "123"))),
    new BsonDocument("$replaceWith", "$Content.CustInfo.CustomerComment")
};

var result = await Collection.Aggregate<CustomerComment>(aggregate)
    .ToListAsync();
```

> Output

[image]